# What do the colours mean in the list of review board dashboard?

Tags: review-board

Recently i have started using Review Board in my project and it is just an amazing tool to have. I am seeing review requests in GREEN, RED, YELLOW colors in the dashboard. What do they exactly mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [manual](http://www.reviewboard.org/docs/manual/dev/users/dashboard/) clearly states on all the date columns.

> This is color-coded to indicate the age.

And from the first image on the [homepage](http://www.reviewboard.org/), red looks to be older, green newer.